# Traverse .config file in exe or web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration, console-application

I'm writing a library that will be used in desktop and web apps. It needs to traverse the section groups in the .config file. I assume I'll need an instance of `System.Configuration.Configuration` to do this. Is there a way to do this that works in desktop and web apps?

Comment: How about XmlTextReader?

Comment: That's fine--although unfortunate--if that's what I have to do. Is there a host-agnostic way of getting the .config file path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with something like this:

```
static Configuration OpenConfiguration() {
    if (HttpContext.Current != null)
        return WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(null);
    return ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
}

static IEnumerable<ConfigurationSectionGroup> GetConfigSectionGroups() {
    var config = OpenConfiguration();
    var stack = new Stack<ConfigurationSectionGroup>();
    stack.Push(config.RootSectionGroup);
    while (stack.Count > 0) {
        var group = stack.Pop();
        yield return group;
        foreach (ConfigurationSectionGroup subGroup in group.SectionGroups) {
            stack.Push(subGroup);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `WebConfigurationManager`/`ConfigurationManager` to read specific configuration sections and return a `ConfigurationSection` object.

Comment: I don't need a specific section, I need to traverse the section groups.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968592/accessing-an-attribute-on-a-configsection-in-a-web-config